# Codeception - How can I get the $scenario property inside a cest method?

Tags: php, codeception

I have a Cest class where I want to use the scenario property of $I, but it's generated as protected and no getter is defined for it. I want to see if the scenario is running or not. How can I do this?

The code is something like this:

```
public function testFunction(ApiGuy $I){

    if ($I->scenario->running()){
    } 

}
```

ApiGuy extends AbstractGuy that has a property: protected $scenario; so $I->scenario is null, as well as $I->getScenario(). I can add a public function to do this, but every time I build the ApiGuy this gets overwritten. Isn't it another way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add it as a parameter:

```
 public function testFunction(ApiGuy $I, $scenario ){

     if ($scenario->running()){
          .....

     } 

 }
```

Comment: i think you don't have to add the full namespace of `$scenario` because it `$scenario` is automatically passed as a second parameter to **Cest classes**.

Here's an excerpt from the documentation:



Each public method of Cest (except those starting with _) will be executed as a test and will receive Actor class as the first parameter and **$scenario variable as the second one**.

Comment: @theUnknown777. Thanks. I have removed the full namespace.